# Javascript addEventListener issue in laravel foreach loop

Tags: javascript, laravel, for-loop, foreach, addeventlistener

I am trying to add javascript inside a laravel blade foreach loop, please refer to the code below.

Here is my orders.blade.php file

```
@foreach ($orders as $order)
  <div class="" id="{{ 'show_summary' . $order->id }}">
    show summary
  </div>

  <div class="d-none" id="{{ 'hide_summary' . $order->id }}">
     Hide Summary
  </div>

  <div class="activeContent" id="{{ 'summary_content' . $order->id }}">
    Summary Content
  </div>
@endforeach
<script>
    var orderIDS = {{ count(App\Models\Order::all()) }};
</script>
```

Here is my javascript file

```
        for (let index = 1; index <= orderIDS; index++) {
          var indexVar = index.toString();
          var ssnew = document.getElementById('show_summary' + indexVar);
          var hsnew = document.getElementById('hide_summary' + indexVar);
          var scnew = document.getElementById('summary_content' + indexVar);
          ssnew.addEventListener('click', function () {
              ssnew.classList.add('d-none');
              hsnew.classList.remove('d-none');
              scnew.classList.remove('activeContent');
          });
          hsnew.addEventListener('click', function () {
              hsnew.classList.add('d-none');
              ssnew.classList.remove('d-none');
              scnew.classList.add('activeContent');
          });
        }
```

For some reason the script is only working on the last element of the for loop. May I know why?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `$order->id` in @foreach doesn't match to `index` in JavaScript for loop. Use `$loop->index` instead of `$order->id` and start loop from `0` in JavaScript `for` loop.

```
@foreach ($orders as $order)
  <div class="" id="{{ 'show_summary' . $loop->index }}">
    show summary
  </div>

  <div class="d-none" id="{{ 'hide_summary' . $loop->index }}">
     Hide Summary
  </div>

  <div class="activeContent" id="{{ 'summary_content' . $loop->index }}">
    Summary Content
  </div>
@endforeach
<script>
    var orderCount = {!! json_encode(App\Models\Order::count()) !!};
</script>
```

```
for (let index = 0; index < orderCount; index++) {
  var ssnew = document.getElementById('show_summary' + index);
  var hsnew = document.getElementById('hide_summary' + index);
  var scnew = document.getElementById('summary_content' + index);
  ssnew.addEventListener('click', function () {
     ssnew.classList.add('d-none');
     hsnew.classList.remove('d-none');
     scnew.classList.remove('activeContent');
  });
  hsnew.addEventListener('click', function () {
     hsnew.classList.add('d-none');
     ssnew.classList.remove('d-none');
     scnew.classList.add('activeContent');
  });
}
```

Comment: This time I get two errors 

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null`

Comment: Hi, `o.oedits`, I've updated my answer. If error again, will you inspect elements and check if all elements are rendered as expected? FYI, use `App\Models\Order::count()` instead of `count(App\Models\Order::all())`. This is definitely more efficient in memory usage.

Comment: Hi @Prime, this time the following error shows, 

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous>`